# Reset CSS3 Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am animating one or more DIVs as they scroll into view. I'm doing this by splitting the animation css into several classes (see below).

The animated DIVs will initially have the classes '*.mpact-animated*' and '*.mpact-animated-pause*'. The DIVs will also have one of the following classes '*.mpact-shake*', '*.mpact-heartbeat*', or '*.mpact-bounce*'. These animation classes are selected by users thus I don't know which is to be implemented.

As the page is scrolled the DIVs are checked via Javascript (see below) to see if they have scrolled into view. If they have the '*.mpact-animated-pause*' class is removed and the '*.mpact-animated-play*' class is added. As the DIVs scroll out of view the '*.mpact-animated-play*' class is removed and the '*.mpact-animated-pause*' class is added.

This does work as planned the first time the DIVs scroll into view but not subsequent times the DIVs scroll into view.

How can I reset the animation so that it will rerun after the DIV scrolls out of view then back into view?

*NOTE:*
The inline styles in the sample div are also selected by the user.

**ANIMATION CSS**

```
.mpact-animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.mpact-animated-play {
    animation-play-state: running !important;
}

.mpact-animated-pause {
    animation-play-state: paused !important;
}    
.mpact-shake {
  -webkit-animation-name: shake;
  animation-name: shake;
}

.mpact-heartbeat {
  -webkit-animation-name: heartbeat;
  animation-name: heartbeat;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 3;
  animation-iteration-count: 3;
}

.mpact-bounce {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
  animation-name: bounce;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 3;
  animation-iteration-count: 3;
}

@keyframes shake { from, to { -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); } 10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% { -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0); transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0); } 20%, 40%, 60%, 80% { -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0); transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0); } }

@keyframes heartbeat { from { -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1); transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1); } 50% { -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05); transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05); } to { -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1); transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1); } }

@keyframes bounce { from, 20%, 53%, 80%, to { -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000); animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000); webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); transform: translate3d(0,0,0); } 40%, 43% { -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060); animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0); transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0); } 70% { -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060); animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0); transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0); } 90% { -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0); transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0); } }
```

**JS**

```
function mpactIsInView(elem) {
    var $elem = jQuery(elem);

    var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != -1) ? 'body' : 'html');
    var viewportTop = jQuery(scrollElem).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + jQuery(window).height();

    var elemTop = Math.round( $elem.offset().top );
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
}

function mpactCheckAnim() {    
    jQuery( ".mpact-sidebar-cta.cta-container" ).each(function( index, element ) {
        if ( mpactIsInView(jQuery( element ) ) ) {
            jQuery( element ).removeClass('mpact-animated-pause');
            jQuery( element ).addClass('mpact-animated-play');
        } else {
            jQuery( element ).removeClass('mpact-animated-play');
            jQuery( element ).addClass('mpact-animated-pause');
        }
    });
}

jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    mpactCheckAnim();
});
```

**SAMPLE DIV**

```
<div class="mpact-sidebar-cta cta-container mpact-animated mpact-animated-pause mpact-shake" style="border-style: dashed; border-width: 3px; border-color: #000; background-color: hsl(130, 97%, 48%);">    
    <div class="mpact-sidebar-cta container-top" style="">                  
        <div class="mpact-sidebar-cta cta-heading-container" style="padding: 20px 20px 5px;">              
            <h2 class="mpact-sidebar-cta heading" style="color: #333;">Heading</h2>        
        </div>    
    </div>    
    <div class="mpact-sidebar-cta container-bottom" style="color: #333;">        
        <div  class="mpact-sidebar-cta cta-content-padding-container" style="padding: 10px 20px;">            
            <div  class="mpact-sidebar-cta cta-content-container" style="">                Enter the text content for the !M CTA.             
            </div><br />            
            <div  class="mpact-sidebar-cta cta-button-container" style="">                
                <a class="x-btn x-btn-global alignright" style="" href="http://www.some-domain.com">Click Here!</a>            
            </div>            
            <div  class="mpact-sidebar-cta cta-call-container" style="">                
                <a class="x-btn x-btn-global alignright" style="" href="tel:+1234567890">Call Us!</a>            
            </div>        
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

**NONANIMATION CSS**

```
.mpact-sidebar-cta.cta-container { width: 100%; display: inline-block; }
. mpact-sidebar-cta.heading { font-size: 20px; line-height: 24px; text-transform:uppercase ; font-weight: 900; -webkit-margin-before: 0em; -webkit-margin-after: 0em; }
. mpact-sidebar-cta.container-top { display: inline-block; width: 100%; }
. mpact-sidebar-cta.container-bottom { display: inline-block; width: 100%; }
. mpact-sidebar-cta.cta-content-padding-container { display: inline-block; width: 100%; }
. mpact-sidebar-cta.cta-content-container { display: inline; }
. mpact-sidebar-cta.cta-button-container { display: inline; }
. mpact-sidebar-cta.cta-call-container { display: none; }

@media (max-width: 1280px) {
/* 13" notebook */

}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
/* 12" netbook, 10" netbook */

}


@media (max-width: 800px) {
/* Kindle Fire HD 8.9,  */

}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
/* Apple iPads and Up  */
    .cta-button-container { display: inline; }
    .cta-call-container   { display: none; }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
/* Apple iPad 1/2/3/mini,  */

}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
/* 480p television */
    .cta-button-container { display: none; }
    .cta-call-container   { display: inline; }
}

@media (max-width: 603px) {
/* Google Nexus 7 */

}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
/* Kindle Fire, Samsung Galaxy Tab */

}

@media (max-width: 533px) {
/* Kindle Fire HD 7 */
    .cta-button-container { display: inline; }
    .cta-call-container   { display: none; }
}

@media (max-width: 360px) {
/* Samsung Galaxy S3/4,  */
    .cta-button-container { display: none; }
    .cta-call-container   { display: inline; }
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
/* Apple iPhone 3/4/5, Samsung Galaxy SII, ASUS Galaxy 7, LG Optimus S, Blackberry 8300  */

}
```

Comment: You should probably removeClass after animation has finished playing.

Comment: Check animate.css docs. They had a nifty event listener example there.

Comment: @hypeJunction removing the class doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is the preset iteration count. There are some tricks around SO if you search.
For your particular case, I would suggest setting iteration count to infinite, and pausing animation by toggling classes. You can `transform: none` on your pause class, in case animation stops at some odd time:

```js
function mpactIsInView(elem) {
  var $elem = jQuery(elem);

  var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != -1) ? 'body' : 'html');
  var viewportTop = jQuery(scrollElem).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + jQuery(window).height();

  var elemTop = Math.round($elem.offset().top);
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

  return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
}

function mpactCheckAnim() {
  jQuery(".mpact-sidebar-cta.cta-container").each(function(index, element) {
    if (mpactIsInView(jQuery(element))) {
      jQuery(element).removeClass('mpact-animated-pause');
      jQuery(element).addClass('mpact-animated-play');
      var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery(element).removeClass('mpact-animated-play');
        jQuery(element).addClass('mpact-animated-pause');
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      jQuery(element).removeClass('mpact-animated-play');
      jQuery(element).addClass('mpact-animated-pause');
    }
  });
}

jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    mpactCheckAnim();
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1000px 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.mpact-animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.mpact-animated-play {
  animation-play-state: running !important;
}
.mpact-animated-pause {
  animation-play-state: paused !important;
  transform: none;
}
.mpact-shake {
  -webkit-animation-name: shake;
  animation-name: shake;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.mpact-heartbeat {
  -webkit-animation-name: heartbeat;
  animation-name: heartbeat;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.mpact-bounce {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
  animation-name: bounce;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes shake {
  from, to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  10%,
  30%,
  50%,
  70%,
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  40%,
  60%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes heartbeat {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes bounce {
  from, 20%, 53%, 80%, to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  43% {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="mpact-sidebar-cta cta-container mpact-animated mpact-animated-pause mpact-shake" style="border-style: dashed; border-width: 3px; border-color: #000; background-color: hsl(130, 97%, 48%);">
    <div class="mpact-sidebar-cta container-top" style="">
      <div class="mpact-sidebar-cta cta-heading-container" style="padding: 20px 20px 5px;">
        <h2 class="mpact-sidebar-cta heading" style="color: #333;">Heading</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mpact-sidebar-cta container-bottom" style="color: #333;">
      <div class="mpact-sidebar-cta cta-content-padding-container" style="padding: 10px 20px;">
        <div class="mpact-sidebar-cta cta-content-container" style="">Enter the text content for the !M CTA.
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="mpact-sidebar-cta cta-button-container" style="">
          <a class="x-btn x-btn-global alignright" style="" href="http://www.some-domain.com">Click Here!</a>
        </div>
        <div class="mpact-sidebar-cta cta-call-container" style="">
          <a class="x-btn x-btn-global alignright" style="" href="tel:+1234567890">Call Us!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First, thank you for taking a look, it is greatly appreciated. I've tried your snippet on safari, chrome, and opera it doesn't work on any of them. I've also moved your code into a JS fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/r3pntjtp/) to no avail. On the chance I wasn't clear (always a possibility)... I need the DIV to animate every time it comes into view after scrolling. Also, each animation should execute the number of times it currently does.

Comment: Hm, odd, works for me here when you Run the snippet.